# How to compute the number of arguments from a method descriptor?

Tags: java, jvm

I would like to know the number of arguments of a method giving its Method Descriptor as specified in [Chapter 4 The class file Format - Section 4.3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.3). Is there any built-in function providing this utility?

Comment: I'm curious about the use-case.  What is driving this need?

Comment: A Java instrumentation engine that I am developing with ASM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do no know built-in method but occasionally I have implemented one.

```
private static Pattern allParamsPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\(.*?\\))");
private static Pattern paramsPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\[?)(C|Z|S|I|J|F|D|(:?L[^;]+;))");


int getMethodParamCount(String methodRefType) {
    Matcher m = allParamsPattern.matcher(methodRefType);
    if (!m.find()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Method signature does not contain parameters");
    }
    String paramsDescriptor = m.group(1);
    Matcher mParam = paramsPattern.matcher(paramsDescriptor);

    int count = 0;
    while (mParam.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

You are welcome to refer to the full source code [here](https://github.com/alexradzin/SafeChain).

Comment: Note that longs and doubles take up two slots.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works... I was working with ASM as well and this is the method that i concocted... been using for some time now...

```
public static int getMethodArgumentCount(String desc) {
 int beginIndex = desc.indexOf('(') + 1;
 int endIndex = desc.lastIndexOf(')');
 String x0 = desc.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);//Extract the part related to the arguments
 String x1 = x0.replace("[", "");//remove the [ symbols for arrays to avoid confusion.
 String x2 = x1.replace(";", "; ");//add an extra space after each semicolon.
 String x3 = x2.replaceAll("L\\S+;", "L");//replace all the substrings starting with L, ending with ; and containing non whitespace characters inbetween with L.
 String x4 = x3.replace(" ", "");//remove the previously inserted spaces.
 return x4.length();//count the number of elements left.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Method#getParameterTypes().length ?

Comment: I am talking about Method Descriptors and not Method type from java.lang.reflect. See updated reference above.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `method.getParameterTypes()`. Which give you a array of parameter types, So you can know how many parameters there is.

Comment: I am talking about Method Descriptors and not Method type from java.lang.reflect. See updated reference above.